# Test case to cover catch block of CompletableFuture get() method

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I want to write a test case for the catch block of a private method in my code below:

I'm calling this method in my test case:

```
public void addValidationResultToValidations(Instrument instrument, AssetDetail assetDetail) {
    List<ValidationResult> validationResults = getValidationResults(instrument, assetDetail);
    //        .... some other logic
}
```

`getValidationResults` is a private method which returns a `list` of `ValidationResult`. Below is the method:

```
private List<ValidationResult> getValidationResults(Instrument instrument, AssetDetail assetDetail) {
    List<CompletableFuture<ValidationResult>> completableFutureList = new ArrayList<>(); // some service call with instrument and assetDetail object returned results
    CompletableFuture<List<ValidationResult>> listCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutureList.size()]))
            .thenApply(v -> completableFutureList.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    try {
        return listCompletableFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("exception {}"+ e);
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So far, I have been trying to throw an exception and assert that an exception is thrown in my test case to cover the catch block of the `ValidationResult` method but kept getting the error below:

```
org.opens4j.AssertionError: Expected java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown
```

Here is my test case:

```
@Test
public void whenGetIsCalledOnCompletableFutureThenThrowException(){
    Instrument instrument = AssetUtils.getInstrument();
    AssetDetail assetDetail = AssetUtils.getAssetDetail();
    CompletableFuture<List<ValidationResult>> badFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    badFuture.completeExceptionally(new Exception());
    assertThrown(Exception.class, () -> {
         service.addValidationResultToValidations(instrument, assetDetail);
    })
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong? How can I cover the catch block in my test case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to simulate a case in your test that will throw the excepted exception. Another way will be to mock the call of `listCompletableFuture.get()` and then throw the `InterruptedException` or the `ExecutionException`

```
Mockito.when(listCompletableFuture.get()).thenThrow(InterruptedException.class)
```

or

```
Mockito.when(listCompletableFuture.get()).thenThrow(ExecutionException.class)
```

Also if you just want to test the exception, there is no issue in mocking this behaviour in isolation.

Comment: When I do this, my test case doesn't stop running. It keeps running until I manually stop the process. I think the `listCompletableFuture.get()` runs into a wait state and never terminates the test case.